# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre pyplot.show() y pyplot.figure.show() en Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trabajando con Matplotlib para generar gráficas, no acabo de entender la diferencia entre estas dos formas de generar y mostrar una gráfica:

Forma 1:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Forma 2:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graph = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
graph.show()
```

Sé que no hacen lo mismo, pero no me queda clara la diferencia. He leído documentación al respecto, pero no me acaba de quedar claro.

¿Alguien me puede explicar por pasos lo que sucede en cada caso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la primera forma estás creando la gráfica de manera programática. Matplotlib guarda en memoria que tu has llamado a `plt.figure()` entonces crea una figura. Luego todas las llamadas que hagas para pintar en la figura como `plt.plot()` actuarán sobre la última figura que has creado llamando a `plt.figure()`, incluso la llamada `plt.show()`.

En cambio, en la segunda estás obteniendo el resultado de la figura `plt.figure()` en una variable. Esta variable es una instancia de la figura. Luego puedes llamar a `plt.show()` o aplicar el método `show()` del objeto `Figure` para mostrarla. Si miras en [la documentación de la función `plt.figure()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) verás que bajo los parámetros, donde indica qué devuelve ("Returns:"), verás que dice que devuelve una instancia de la figura, la que estás guardando para luego operar sobre ella. Esta sería la manera adecuada si queremos operar sobre varias figuras.